# javafx.graphics not in module graph

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I kept encountering this error with jdk 9 and above on my projects. Seems like javafx isnt present. However, it manages to build fine but when I run the project, it does not show any gui.

[image]
Can anyone shed some light as to why javafx.graphics isn't detected in module graph?

Comment: You need `module-info.java` with proper requires, see https://carlfx.wordpress.com/2016/04/26/a-javafx-helloworld-using-java-9s-project-jigsaw-in-60-seconds/. Or switch back to Java 8 language level.

Comment: Hmm I tried on vscode using java extensions and it works fine. This issue might just be an intellij thing